# getClass() in equals() gives an unexpected result for my entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've a method that dissociate two object.
At the beginning of the method i retrieve from the DB(SpringData JPA/HIBERNATE) both the objects, that we well name object1 of type A and object2 of type B, then i compare `object1.getB().equals(object2)` and though the `object1.getB` is the same of `object2` the result is `false`. Why? If i debug the method i can see that object2 and the property B of the object 2 have the same class that is `B_$$_jvst1a4_5`. Why have this strange name? shouldn't be only B? In the `equals` method infact when compare

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

i obtain `B != B_$$_jvst1a4_5` and so return false.

Someone can explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use libraries that generate classes at runtime (proxy classes). 
You should never rely on `getClass()` of these proxy classes to compare class of two instances as you don't have the hand and guarantee on how Hibernate (here) and Spring (as you use it) generate them.
As alternative in your `equals()` you should use the `instanceof` operator to determine whether an object is an instance of a class known at compile time :

```
if (myObject instanceof MyClass){
   ...
}
```

Whatever, `instanceof` should always be favored in `equals()` implementation to not break the method behavior for subclass instances.

Comment: lol "always"? I would say never. You break the symmetry principle. B is instance of A, but A is not instance of B. `instanceof` must only be used inside a final class, but a JPA entity must not be final. `getClass` is the only option, really. The proxy class ought to be different for different classes, as indicated by the SO question. He's comparing a new object with one that is managed (has a persistent state). Of course they shouldn't be equal. JPA 3 section writes: "Two entities of the same abstract schema type are equal if and only if they have the same primary key value".

Answer (score 1):

to be safe, you should compare the proxy class.
Here is a sample implementation of equals and hashcode from 'Jpa Buddy'.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), book.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
}
```

instanceof is less efficient and should not be used here.